# MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN sometimes does not click

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to automate some spreadsheet generation in an external application, and to do so have been using mouse events and sendkeys. For the most part, it is fully functional, except sometimes when the macro calls for a leftclick, it fails to actually click.

So far, I have tried introducing longer sleeps in between clicks and in the mouse event itself, but that does not seem to be enough.

The left click sub:

```vb
'Mouse left click
Sub LeftClick()
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  Sleep 100
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub
```

Following each left click I also have a `Sleep(1000)` call. While this works well over 90% of the time it is called, I need it to work 100% of the time.

EDIT: Adding some more code per request to hopefully try and clear up any confusion.

Mouse events is just a system library that I am referencing:

```vb
'Declare mouse events
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN As Long = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP As Long = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10
```

Comment: Depending on the desired output, it may be appropriate to have `Do While` or `Do Until` for different aspects.  `Send Keys` is prone to many issues, similar to the timing you've averted to with use of `sleep`, but there are other issues such as location of the initial cell/cursor/etc.  As such, knowing more about what is happening in the overall scope of the procedure may be appropriate to diagnose what is failing.  Not sure if it's worth a cross-post, but posting on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be beneficial to possibly circumvent some of the issues.

Comment: Please provide more of your code for us to understand what it is you are attempting to do. What is **mouse_event**? what are you trying to click?

Comment: I'd recommend checking where you are in the spreadsheet before sending the click.  As said, where do you need to be? Are you left clicking in a cell/column etc.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the responses. @Zac, I have added the mouse events code to the post. It is just system libraries that should simulate the actions of the hardware mouse.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, I am attempting to click on an external application, not on the workbook. The position of the cursor prior to failing to click is correct (I can see it move onto the button), so it seems like it is just the actual clicking that is failing.

Comment: What type of application is it?

Comment: @Cyril thank you for the suggestion. If you don't mind me asking, what did you mean by Do While as an alternative to Send Keys? My understanding is the only way to mimic hardware input is through the latter, but if you have any resources on alternatives I am eager to learn.

Comment: Hi Zac, the application is an insurance illustration software. You input some basic information like sex, age, smoker status, etc., and then it outputs a spreadsheet showing your yearly premiums, death benefits, and so on.

Comment: Perhaps look at the API way of developing this, finding the app, then the button and fire it's left click event.

Comment: In addition to previous comment Number 5 on this https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-plus-of-my-favorite-windows-api-functions-to-use-in-office-applications/ would be where i'd start this journey.

Comment: @J.S the use of `do while` or `do until` would be to replace the `sleep` function, where you may have something happening in the background which is not visible until that `send keys` function has completed.  My apologies for the confusion.